# {email} and {url} returning admins info, not comment authors info

Tags: templates, comments, export

**I’m trying to use these two template systems (xml templates, php enabled) to export EE (EE core version 2.7) blog entries into WordPress .wxr import format:**

These two templates are in a template group called export. One template is called index, and the other is called comments. I open index in a new window and view source to see the .wxr data.

The one template directly below (I was using this before a two template system was suggested) outputs the four blog posts with the `status="Home Featured"` and all the comments, but the comments don't have the original author or URL but has the admins info, as noted in the original question title.

```
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:excerpt="http://wordpress.org/export/1.1/excerpt/"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:wp="http://wordpress.org/export/1.1/"
>

<channel>
    <title>{site_name}</title>
    <link>{site_url}</link>

    <pubDate></pubDate>
    <language>en</language>
    <wp:wxr_version>1.1</wp:wxr_version>
    <wp:base_site_url>http://domain.com/demo1/</wp:base_site_url>
    <wp:base_blog_url>http://domain.com/demo1</wp:base_blog_url>

    <generator>http://wordpress.org/?v=3.1.2</generator>

{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" status="Home Featured" orderby="date" sort="desc" limit="100" offset="0" rdf="off" dynamic="no"} 

    <item>
        <title>{exp:xml_encode}{title}{/exp:xml_encode}</title>
        <link></link>
        <pubDate>{entry_date format="%r"}</pubDate>
        <dc:creator><![CDATA[{author}]]></dc:creator>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://domain.com/demo1/?p={entry_id}</guid>
        <description></description>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[{if blog-body}{blog-body}{if:elseif cc_content}{cc_content}{if:else}{article_content}{/if}]]></content:encoded>
        <excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[{if blog_short}{blog_short}{if:elseif cc_teaser}{cc_teaser}{if:else}{teaser}{/if}]]></excerpt:encoded>
        <wp:post_id></wp:post_id>
        <wp:post_date>{entry_date format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"}</wp:post_date>
        <wp:post_date_gmt>{gmt_date format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"}</wp:post_date_gmt>
        <wp:comment_status>open</wp:comment_status>
        <wp:ping_status>open</wp:ping_status>
        <wp:post_name>{url_title}</wp:post_name>
        <wp:status>{if status == "open"}publish{if:elseif status == "review"}pending{if:elseif status == "closed"}private{if:elseif status == "draft"}draft{if:else}publish{/if}</wp:status>
        <wp:post_parent>0</wp:post_parent>
        <wp:menu_order>0</wp:menu_order>
        <wp:post_type>post</wp:post_type>
        <wp:post_password></wp:post_password>
        <wp:is_sticky>0</wp:is_sticky>
{categories}
        <category domain="category" nicename="{if category_url_title == "uncategorized"}media{if:else}{category_url_title}{/if}"><![CDATA[{if category_name == "Uncategorized"}Media{if:else}{category_name}{/if}]]></category>
{/categories}
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_edit_last</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[1]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
{if article_links}
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>Associated Links</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[{article_links}]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
{/if}
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_su_rich_snippet_type</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[none]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_encloseme</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[1]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>


{/exp:channel:entries}
{exp:comment:entries sort="desc" entry_id="{embed:entry_id}"}


        <wp:comment>
            <wp:comment_id>{comment_id}</wp:comment_id>
            <wp:comment_author><![CDATA[{name}]]></wp:comment_author>
            <wp:comment_author_email>{email}</wp:comment_author_email>
            <wp:comment_author_url>{url}</wp:comment_author_url>
            <wp:comment_author_IP>{ip_address}</wp:comment_author_IP>
            <wp:comment_date>{comment_date format="%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s"}</wp:comment_date>
            <wp:comment_date_gmt>{gmt_comment_date format="%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s"}</wp:comment_date_gmt>
            <wp:comment_content><![CDATA[{comment}]]></wp:comment_content>
            <wp:comment_approved>1</wp:comment_approved>
            <wp:comment_type></wp:comment_type>
            <wp:comment_parent>0</wp:comment_parent>
            <wp:comment_user_id>0</wp:comment_user_id>
        </wp:comment>
{/exp:comment:entries}
    </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

**9/12/13 edit:** **This two template system breaks:** index only outputs one blog post and I don't think it correctly passes the blog post info to the comments template (so that the comments are linked by post ID to the blog post) because upon WP import, WP says the author doesn't exist and doesn't import any comments.

**"index" template:**

```
     <rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:excerpt="http://wordpress.org/export/1.1/excerpt/"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:wp="http://wordpress.org/export/1.1/"
>

<channel>
    <title>{site_name}</title>
    <link>{site_url}</link>

    <pubDate></pubDate>
    <language>en</language>
    <wp:wxr_version>1.1</wp:wxr_version>
    <wp:base_site_url>http://domain.com/demo1/</wp:base_site_url>
    <wp:base_blog_url>http://domain.com/demo1</wp:base_blog_url>

    <generator>http://wordpress.org/?v=3.1.2</generator>

{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" status="Home Featured" orderby="date" sort="desc" limit="10" offset="0" rdf="off" dynamic="no"} 

    <item>
        <title>{exp:xml_encode}{title}{/exp:xml_encode}</title>
        <link></link>
        <pubDate>{entry_date format="%r"}</pubDate>
        <dc:creator><![CDATA[{author}]]></dc:creator>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://domain.com/demo1/?p={entry_id}</guid>
        <description></description>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[{if blog-body}{blog-body}{if:elseif cc_content}{cc_content}{if:else}{article_content}{/if}]]></content:encoded>
        <excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[{if blog_short}{blog_short}{if:elseif cc_teaser}{cc_teaser}{if:else}{teaser}{/if}]]></excerpt:encoded>
        <wp:post_id></wp:post_id>
        <wp:post_date>{entry_date format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"}</wp:post_date>
        <wp:post_date_gmt>{gmt_date format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"}</wp:post_date_gmt>
        <wp:comment_status>open</wp:comment_status>
        <wp:ping_status>open</wp:ping_status>
        <wp:post_name>{url_title}</wp:post_name>
        <wp:status>{if status == "open"}publish{if:elseif status == "review"}pending{if:elseif status == "closed"}private{if:elseif status == "draft"}draft{if:else}publish{/if}</wp:status>
        <wp:post_parent>0</wp:post_parent>
        <wp:menu_order>0</wp:menu_order>
        <wp:post_type>post</wp:post_type>
        <wp:post_password></wp:post_password>
        <wp:is_sticky>0</wp:is_sticky>
{categories}
        <category domain="category" nicename="{if category_url_title == "uncategorized"}media{if:else}{category_url_title}{/if}"><![CDATA[{if category_name == "Uncategorized"}Media{if:else}{category_name}{/if}]]></category>
{/categories}
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_edit_last</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[1]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
{if article_links}
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>Associated Links</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[{article_links}]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
{/if}
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_su_rich_snippet_type</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[none]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_encloseme</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[1]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>


    {embed="blog/comments" entry_id="{entry_id}"}

{/exp:channel:entries}

    </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

**"comments" template**

```
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:excerpt="http://wordpress.org/export/1.1/excerpt/"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:wp="http://wordpress.org/export/1.1/"
>

<channel>
    <title>{site_name}</title>
    <link>{site_url}</link>

    <pubDate></pubDate>
    <language>en</language>
    <wp:wxr_version>1.1</wp:wxr_version>
    <wp:base_site_url>http://domain.com/demo1/</wp:base_site_url>
    <wp:base_blog_url>http://domain.com/demo1</wp:base_blog_url>

    <generator>http://wordpress.org/?v=3.1.2</generator>

{exp:comment:entries sort="desc" entry_id="{embed:entry_id}"}

<item>
        <wp:comment>
            <wp:comment_id>{comment_id}</wp:comment_id>
            <wp:comment_author><![CDATA[{name}]]></wp:comment_author>
            <wp:comment_author_email>{email}</wp:comment_author_email>
            <wp:comment_author_url>{url}</wp:comment_author_url>
            <wp:comment_author_IP>{ip_address}</wp:comment_author_IP>
            <wp:comment_date>{comment_date format="%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s"}</wp:comment_date>
            <wp:comment_date_gmt>{gmt_comment_date format="%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s"}</wp:comment_date_gmt>
            <wp:comment_content><![CDATA[{comment}]]></wp:comment_content>
            <wp:comment_approved>1</wp:comment_approved>
            <wp:comment_type></wp:comment_type>
            <wp:comment_parent>0</wp:comment_parent>
            <wp:comment_user_id>0</wp:comment_user_id>
        </wp:comment>
</item>
{/exp:comment:entries}
</rss>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saw your post in meta - maybe a new answer which distills the entire thread you and Anna have created will be of help?

You do need two templates. The first will begin your document, and then list each channel entry, and then close the document. Within that template's `channel:entries` loop, you will embed your "comments" template, which will run once for every entry, and will list all comments for that particular entry, based on the `entry_id` you pass it via the embed.

So, using your code, the first template looks like this:

```
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:excerpt="http://wordpress.org/export/1.1/excerpt/"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:wp="http://wordpress.org/export/1.1/"
>
<channel>
    <title>{site_name}</title>
    <link>{site_url}</link>
    <pubDate></pubDate>
    <language>en</language>
    <wp:wxr_version>1.1</wp:wxr_version>
    <wp:base_site_url>http://domain.com/demo1/</wp:base_site_url>
    <wp:base_blog_url>http://domain.com/demo1</wp:base_blog_url>
    <generator>http://wordpress.org/?v=3.1.2</generator>

{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" status="Home Featured" orderby="date" sort="desc" limit="100" offset="0" rdf="off" dynamic="no"} 
    <item>
        <title>{exp:xml_encode}{title}{/exp:xml_encode}</title>
        <link></link>
        <pubDate>{entry_date format="%r"}</pubDate>
        <dc:creator><![CDATA[{author}]]></dc:creator>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://domain.com/demo1/?p={entry_id}</guid>
        <description></description>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[{if blog-body}{blog-body}{if:elseif cc_content}{cc_content}{if:else}{article_content}{/if}]]></content:encoded>
        <excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[{if blog_short}{blog_short}{if:elseif cc_teaser}{cc_teaser}{if:else}{teaser}{/if}]]></excerpt:encoded>
        <wp:post_id></wp:post_id>
        <wp:post_date>{entry_date format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"}</wp:post_date>
        <wp:post_date_gmt>{gmt_date format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"}</wp:post_date_gmt>
        <wp:comment_status>open</wp:comment_status>
        <wp:ping_status>open</wp:ping_status>
        <wp:post_name>{url_title}</wp:post_name>
        <wp:status>{if status == "open"}publish{if:elseif status == "review"}pending{if:elseif status == "closed"}private{if:elseif status == "draft"}draft{if:else}publish{/if}</wp:status>
        <wp:post_parent>0</wp:post_parent>
        <wp:menu_order>0</wp:menu_order>
        <wp:post_type>post</wp:post_type>
        <wp:post_password></wp:post_password>
        <wp:is_sticky>0</wp:is_sticky>
{categories}
        <category domain="category" nicename="{if category_url_title == "uncategorized"}media{if:else}{category_url_title}{/if}"><![CDATA[{if category_name == "Uncategorized"}Media{if:else}{category_name}{/if}]]></category>
{/categories}
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_edit_last</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[1]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
{if article_links}
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>Associated Links</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[{article_links}]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
{/if}
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_su_rich_snippet_type</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[none]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_encloseme</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[1]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        {embed="blog/comments" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    </item>
{/exp:channel:entries}
</channel>
</rss>
```

Then, inside of **blog/comments**:

```
{exp:comment:entries sort="desc" entry_id="{embed:entry_id}"}
        <wp:comment>
            <wp:comment_id>{comment_id}</wp:comment_id>
            <wp:comment_author><![CDATA[{name}]]></wp:comment_author>
            <wp:comment_author_email>{email}</wp:comment_author_email>
            <wp:comment_author_url>{url}</wp:comment_author_url>
            <wp:comment_author_IP>{ip_address}</wp:comment_author_IP>
            <wp:comment_date>{comment_date format="%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s"}</wp:comment_date>
            <wp:comment_date_gmt>{gmt_comment_date format="%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s"}</wp:comment_date_gmt>
            <wp:comment_content><![CDATA[{comment}]]></wp:comment_content>
            <wp:comment_approved>1</wp:comment_approved>
            <wp:comment_type></wp:comment_type>
            <wp:comment_parent>0</wp:comment_parent>
            <wp:comment_user_id>0</wp:comment_user_id>
        </wp:comment>
{/exp:comment:entries}
```

(The reason the comments chunk needs to be embedded is because there can be variable collisions between the `channel:entries` tag and the `comment:entries` tag.)

Comment: Do both of these templates go in the same template group? And what should each template be named? index and comments, as I have in my question? Right now, I get the posts but not the comments.

Comment: My template group is called export and the template file is called index, so the URL I'm viewing and viewing source on is domain.com/export

Comment: The location of the templates relative to each other is actually irrelevant, so long as you use the correct embed path for where the `comments` template is actually located. Also, I see you have `channel="blog" status="Home Featured"` as `channel:entries` parameters - is that correct for your setup?

Comment: Yes, the channel and status are correct; they result in the post output I want. Posts are showing up in the output, but not comments.  What is the correct path to the "comments" template is both templates are in the same template group?

Comment: If your template group is called `export`, and you have placed the `comments` template inside that group, then the embed path is `export/comments`. You'll need to change that path in the first template code chunk I posted, near the bottom.

Comment: Ah, this appears to work. I will try the import to WP later today....

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Try adding dynamic="no" to your `exp:comment:entries` tag. I would also add the channel="" parameter to the tag:</strike>

```
{exp:comment:entries sort="desc" entry_id="{embed:entry_id}" dynamic="no" channel="XXXX"}
```

Also, confirm that {embed:entry_id} is printing out the correct ID in your embed.

---

If that doesn't work, make sure your `exp:comment:entries` is NOT inside a `exp:channel:entries` tag.

---

**EDIT (September 10, 2013)**
Your templates must be setup correctly to get the data you are wanting. From what I think you're trying to do, you need to setup this way with two templates. My code sample below is really dumbed down.

In your first template add the channel:entries tag and add an {embed} tag to a second template to which you pass the entry's {entry_id}.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog"} 
    {embed="blog/comments" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

In the second template, you call the entry_id using {embed:entry_id} in the comment:entries tag.

```
{exp:comment:entries entry_id="{embed:entry_id}"}
{/exp:comment:entries}
```

NOTE: This will be resource intensive if you are printing out lots and lots of data. I wouldn't only use this to do a one off export of entries and comments which seems to be what you're doing. If you get a white screen, you will need to increase PHP memory or limit the number of entries that you are calling.

Comment: Thanks, the exp:comment:entries is inside of a channel tag. All my posts, etc, export OK, and the comments themselves, but not the url or email. Is that the fatal flaw: the exp:comment:entries inside a channel:entries tag?

Comment: Yes, move the tag outside the channel:entries field and it will work correctly.

Comment: Your first ideas didn't work, so yes, it must be the nested tags. I added the whole code block above; can you suggest how I move the tags? Thanks.

Comment: Just move it outside of the channel:entries tag... So to the bottom of the code... You're passing the entry_id to the comment:entries tag through your embed with {embed:entry_id} which is telling the tag what data to grab...

Comment: Ah, thanks, that works, somewhat. But now, no matter what I have for a limit and an offset, I get only one post and its comments (with the email and URL), rather than all of the posts.

Comment: Add `dynamic="no"` to your `{exp:channel:entries ...}` tag

Comment: @Stephen Callender, nope, doesn't help. And Anna_MediaGirl, but now I get all the posts, but the only comments I get are for the last post. Still some sort of loop issue.

Comment: I think the issue is you don't have your template(s) set up correctly. Your code example uses {embed:entry_id} for the entry_id value... this indicates you are passing the value to this template from another template using an embed. Is this the case? Can I ask what your EE experience is? Is this code you wrote or did you copy it from somewhere else? In the end, you have to tell the comments:entries tag which entry_id to pull comments for... you do this by passing an entry_id to the tag via URL or via embed template.

Comment: I am confident your templates aren't set up correctly. I edited my answer above with a code example...

Comment: Thanks, I don't have that much experience wit EE; I'm trying different methods to export to WordPress. This method worked on a EE install without comments. Using two templates is what other methods do, so I need to try it. But does it matter what I name the templates? Is the first template called "entries" and the second called "comments"?

Comment: You can name the templates anything you like.

Comment: Well, thanks, but the two template system breaks; it only exports one post rather than four, and the comment data is broken. Seems still to be a loop issue. To import the comments separately from the post, the post ID must be passed to the comments. I added all code above. Can you see the errors?

Comment: The code I posted should work perfectly. The code will loop through entries and print out the comments specific to that entry. You'll need to post the current template code that isn't working some where so we can see what is causing it not to work.

Comment: You might also just want to pay someone to do this for you. It should take 5 minutes. It's a very quick thing to do.

Comment: Is this the url you are using to call this index template?  www.domain.com/blog

Comment: My template group is called export and the template file is called index, so the URL I'm viewing and viewing source on is domain.com/export

Comment: You'll need to adjust the embed code to your template specifics... which I think should be: {embed="export/comments"}